# Change Text in Shop By box of Magento

Tags: magento

I'm working on a [website in Magento](http://guardianbreeders.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=princess) and by default, it lists the categories as 'Category'. However, I'm looking to change this to say Breeds instead.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

in app/design/frontend/default/THEME/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml, replace line 47 with:

```
<dt><?= $this->__($_filter->getName()) == 'Category' ? 'Breeds' : $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
```